# Detect newly created file, just edited file

Tags: c#, .net, interrupt

I am trying to read a file on a timely basis the moment an edit or creation occurs.  There is another piece of hardware that creates files to a folder which i wish to access (on a timely basis).

How does one go about detecting the creation a newly edited or created file using C# .net.  I do not want to poll the folder on a periodic basis as the machine could potentially write several times in between the polling time interval.  i.e. I want to avoid:

- File 1 (created)                       10:00:04AM
- Poll file 1 ( no data lost )           10:00:05AM
- File 1 (overwritten with new data)     10:00:07AM
- Poll File 1 ( no data lost )           10:00:10AM
- File 1 (overwritten with new data)     10:00:12AM
- File 1 (overwritten with new data)     10:00:14AM
- Poll File 1 ( 10:00:12AM data lost)    10:00:15AM

Answer (score 6):

It's simple, use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Comment: Be aware that the FileSystemWatcher (and the underlying Win32 API) does not cope well with network files see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151804/system-io-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-network-server-folder-performance-cons

Comment: @adam straughan Yes, thanks for pointing this out. @user691770 can you please specify if it's a local or network file?

Answer (score 5):

I think the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b36854c3.aspx) class. It allows you to watch specific directory (you can also apply filter for a file type) and if the file is changed the event will be raised.

Here you have sample code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.enableraisingevents.aspx):

```
// Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = args[1];
/* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
the renaming of files or directories. */
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
// Only watch text files.
watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

// Add event handlers.
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

// Begin watching.
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

where `OnChanged` and `OnRenamed` are events handlers with your logic.