# How do I monitor a drive shared through parallels?

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, parallels

I have a Windows 8 VM running in Parallels on OSX.  The VM is set up so that my home directory on Mac is shared as a mapped network drive.

I'm writing an application which performs an action whenever a specific file changes.  Up until this point, I've been using polling, but I'd much rather respond to events.

I'm trying to use something like `FileSystemWatcher`, but for some reason, it's not raising changed events on the parallels drive.  I know there must be some way to monitor that drive for changes, though, because Visual Studio responds to file changes on the drive.

Is `FileSystemWatcher` able to monitor a drive mapped through parallels, or is there a better option?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151804/system-io-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-network-server-folder-performance-con - perhaps the way their server is setup it doesn't supply that data.

Comment: As I mentioned, Visual Studio seems to monitor files on the share properly, so there must be **some** way to do this.