# Tracking changes in a directory programmacticaly

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, directory, delphi-7

I have to write a litle app that will process files saved in a given dir. I doesn´t pleases me the idea of writing infinite loops, timers and that kind of stuff.

I´d like to know if there if (I would bet a finger that there is!) there is any windows API that would send my app a message for any file saved in that given dir.

Comment: +1 for being willing to trade digits for WinAPI functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadDirectoryChangesW is non-trivial to use correctly.  There is a working sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorychangewatcher.aspx).  I have worked with production code closely derived from this, and I've found no better sample to work from.

Note that there are known issues with the API (admittedly corner cases that may not affect you) that are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254/how-to-keep-readdirectorychangesw-from-missing-file-changes) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2005/10/07/478396.aspx), and further suggestions on usage [here](http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html).

Comment: Yes that sucks. I will fix this.

Comment: Fixed links, one website appears to be broken so I removed that

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465).

Comment: Alternatively, FindFirstChangeNotification() and/or SHChangeNotifyRegister() can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) funciton too. Exist an component called [`TJvChangeNotify`](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/unit.php?Id=3067) from the [JEDI JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) collection wich encapsules this function which makes it easier to use.